# My modal doesn't close when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html

My modal doesn't close when clicking outside. My javascript is fine, so I think my problem is with my html, so if anyone could help find where I messed up I am very grateful.

I tried to change both to see if something works but I wasn't lucky.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container1">
    <div id="branding">
      <img src="image/logo.png">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <button id="myBtn" class="button">ABOUT US</button>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h2>Welcome</h2>
              s
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>We are a New York based salon and spa, stablished in 1991. We have the best professionals to meet your needs.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <img id="img" src="image/logo3.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Without the Javascript, there is no [MCVE], which means there's no way to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: The HTML in your question does not contain an element with class of `close`, `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` is going to match nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I trying deleting it to see if it worked and it didn't

Comment: This is why it's important to have proper debugging in your code. Try adding after `if (event.target == modal) { ... }` the following: `else { console.log(event.target); }` to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: Ok, I kinda fixed, now just my first button is working right, and I dont know why the others aren't. I made a copy of the div for each button and just changed the class for moda2, modal3, etc. And replaced the "modal"s and "myModal" with "modal2" "myModal2", it's probably a silly idea but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I kinda fixed, just my first button (about us) is working, I did a copy o the script and added a number like so.

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
   }
}


   // Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
   modal2.style.display = "block";
```

}

```
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
   modal2.style.display = "none";
```

}

```
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a "Close" background,
It will display (hide and show ) with modal events only.

Check below code :

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalBG = document.getElementById('myModalClose');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalBG.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 modalBG.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
       modal.style.display = "none";
    modalBG.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```css
.close{
 display:none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1040;
 background-color: #000;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
 <li><button id="myBtn" class="button">ABOUT US</button></div>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="myModalClose" class="close">sa</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="width:300px">
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
   <h2>Welcome</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
   <p>We are a New York based salon and spa, stablished in 1991. We have the best professionals to meet your needs.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now user clicks on light black background, the model and that background will be disappeared.